# Flutter ListTile title overflow issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm displaying a long text inside ListTile's `title` using the following code and I'm having UI issue with the `Text` overflow feature:

```dart
ListTile(
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
  leading: SizedBox(
    width: 32.0,
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 32.0,
        height: 32.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: HexColor.fromHex(_clientStatusList.first.color)
              .withOpacity(0.2),
          border: Border.all(
              color: HexColor.fromHex(_clientStatusList.first.color)),
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Icon(
          CustomIcons.customer_important,
          size: 14.0,
          color: HexColor.fromHex(_clientStatusList.first.color),
        )),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  title: Text(
    _clientStatusList.map((e) => e.name).join(", "),
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
  subtitle: Text("Status"),
),
```

Result from the above code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Euf.png

Result without `maxLines` and `overflow`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWOpF.png

I guess that the expected result is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMoT.png

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F96, locale en-IL)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) fo maxLine says:

> If this is 1 (the default), the text will not wrap, but will scroll horizontally instead.

so, the output is right according to widget.

I would suggest [link 1](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) and [link 2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4128) to take a look.

NB: You can try with `Expanded()` Widget, sometimes it is handy to use full empty space .